# I can't fix the 'video system not initialized' issue in python

Tags: python

I wrote this simple program on Raspberry Pi from the user guide. The problem is, that when I run it, Python says that video system not declared in line 29 (for event in pygame.event.get():). I tried initializing pygame twice, but it didn't work. Any suggestions how can I fix it?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pygame, sys, time, random
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()
playSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
pygame.display.set_caption('Raspberry Snake')
redColour = pygame.Color(255, 0, 0)
blackColour = pygame.Color(0, 0, 0)
whiteColour = pygame.Color(255, 255, 255)
greyColour = pygame.Color(150, 150, 150)
snakePosition = [100,100]
snakeSegments = [[100,100],[80,100],[60,100]]
raspberryPosition = [300,300]
raspberrySpawned = 1
direction = 'right'
changeDirection = direction
def gameOver():
    gameOveerFont = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 72)
    gameOverSurf = gameOverFont.render('Game Over', True, greyColour)
    gameOverRect = gameOverSurf.get_rect()
    gameOverRect.midtop = (320, 10)
    playSurface.blit(gameOverSurf, gameOverRect)
    pygame.display.flip()
    time.sleep(5)
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                changeDirection = 'right'
            if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                changeDirection = 'left'
            if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                changeDirection = 'up'
            if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                changeDirection = 'down'
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(QUIT))
if changeDirection == 'right' and not direction == 'left':
    direction = changeDirection
if changeDirection == 'left' and not direction == 'right':
    direction = changeDirection
if changeDirection == 'up' and not direction == 'down':
    direction = changeDirection
if changeDirection == 'down' and not direction == 'up':
    direction = changeDirection
if direction == 'right':
    snakePosition[0] += 20
if direction == 'left':
    snakePosition[0] -= 20
if direction == 'up':
    snakePosition[1] -= 20
if direction == 'down':
    snakePosition[1] += 20
snakeSegments.insert(0,list(snakePosition))
if snakePosition[0] == raspberryPosition[0] and snakePosition[1] == raspberryPosition[1]:
    raspberrySpawned = 0
else:
    snakeSegments.pop()
if raspberrySpawned == 0:
    x = random.randrange(1,32)
    y = random.randrange(1,24)
    raspberryPosition = [int(x*20),int(y*20)]
raspberrySpawned = 1
playSurface.fill(blackColour)
for position in snakeSegments:
    pygame.draw.rect(playSurface,whiteColour,Rect (position[0], position[1], 20, 20))
    pygame.draw.rect(playSurface,redColour,Rect (raspberryPosition[0], raspberryPosition[1], 20, 20))
pygame.display.flip()
if snakePosition[0] > 620 or snakePosition[0] < 0:
    gameOver()
if snakePosition[1] > 460 or snakePosition[1] < 0:
    gameOver()
for snakeBody in snakeSegments[1:]:
    if snakePosition[0] == snakeBody[0] and snakePosition[1] == snakeBody[1]:
        gameOver()
fpsClock.tick(20)}
```

Comment: This is a mess, there's even a curly brace at the end of your code.

Comment: Please fix the indentation, you're obviously not ticking the clock outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

1) Have you installed PyGame correctly?

2) If so... explore around with the locals. See if there's a specific `pygame.video` initilization.

3) Or, try using another IDE, like IDLE

I hope I helped!